# How to make Keras data generator work under numpy array of images?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I got an error on generating data for Keras. I am establishing a code for cloud identification. The layers are simplified because it is too long. This code is expected to get id(file name) and label(train_y) from a csv file then use the images in images directory. This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
import cv2 
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow.python.keras
import keras
import os
from PIL import Image
from numpy import asarray

adam = Adam(learning_rate=0.0001)

train_data_map = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/owenc/Desktop/WeatherIdentify/input/cloud-type-classification2/train.csv')
img_path = 'C:/Users/owenc/Desktop/WeatherIdentify/input/cloud-type-classification2/images/train'
sub_class = os.listdir(img_path)
checkpoint_path = "C:\\Users\\owenc\\Desktop\\WeatherIdentify\\codes\\cp.ckpt"
checkpoint_dir = os.path.dirname(checkpoint_path)

# Create a callback that saves the model's weights
cp_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=checkpoint_path,
                                                 save_weights_only=True,
                                                 verbose=1)

#class_names = ['cirriform clouds', 'high cumuliform clouds', 'stratocumulus clouds', 'cumulus clouds', 'cumulonimbus clouds', 'stratiform clouds', 'clear sky']

cases_count = train_data_map['label'].value_counts()
num_class = 7
epochs = 100
batch_size = 100

train_data_arr = []
train_data_label_arr = []
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    featurewise_center=True,
    featurewise_std_normalization=True,
    rotation_range=20,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    validation_split=0.2)
for idx in range(len(train_data_arr)):
    train_data_label_arr.append(train_data_map.iloc[idx]['label'])
    train_data_arr.append(train_data_map.iloc[idx]['id'])

train_data_label_np = np.array(train_data_label_arr)
train_data = np.array([np.array(cv2.resize(cv2.imread(fname),244,244)) for fname in train_data_arr])
'''
for fname in train_data_arr:
    Img = Image.open(os.path.join(img_path, str(fname)))
    Img.resize((244,244))
    np.append(train_data, np.array(Img))
'''
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size = (5,5),padding = 'Same', 
                 activation ='relu', input_shape = (224,224,3)))
model.add(Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size = (5,5),padding = 'Same', 
                 activation ='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))


model.add(Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size = (3,3),padding = 'Same', 
                 activation ='relu'))
model.add(Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size = (3,3),padding = 'Same', 
                 activation ='relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2), strides=(2,2)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))


model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256, activation = "relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_class, activation = "softmax"))
model.build()
model.summary()
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'], optimizer=adam)
#TODO test

train_gen = train_datagen.flow(train_data, train_data_label_np, batch_size=batch_size)
print(train_gen)
history = model.fit(train_gen,
                epochs = epochs,
                steps_per_epoch=100 // batch_size,callbacks=[cp_callback])
model.save('supermod100.h5','C:\\Users\\owenc\\Desktop\\WeatherIdentify\\models')
```

and here is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\owenc\Desktop\WeatherIdentify\codes\main.py", line 88, in <module>
    train_gen = train_datagen.flow(train_data, train_data_label_np, batch_size=batch_size)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\owenc\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\keras\src\preprocessing\image.py", line 1545, in flow
    return NumpyArrayIterator(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\owenc\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\keras\src\preprocessing\image.py", line 758, in __init__
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: ('Input data in `NumpyArrayIterator` should have rank 4. You passed an array with shape', (0,))
PS C:\Users\owenc\Desktop\WeatherIdentify>
```

I tried to edit the numpy generation`train_data = np.array([np.array(cv2.resize(cv2.imread(fname),244,244)) for fname in train_data_arr])`  but I am unable to understand what the error want meto do thus unabl to do actions that works.

Comment: print the shapes of both your arrays, and you will find your problem, seems the arrays are empty.

Comment: how can i solve that?